# Excel-VBA - Format data in Column to Delimited

Tags: excel, delimited, vba

Need help making Col D "Delimited" from cell D2 to the last cell in Col D that is not blank. I used the Record Macro to try to just steal the code but it does not seem to be working. Can anybody explain how to edit this code so that it will work or provide a new code that does what I am asking.

```
Sub Delimit ()
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Columns("D"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub Delimit()
With Workbooks("Workbook Name")
    With .Sheets("Your Sheet Name Here")
       .Range("d2:" & .Range("d" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address).TextToColumns Destination:=.Range("D2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
         TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
         Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
         :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What line errors out on you? Did you input your sheet name?

Comment: Try the updated. It may be that your sheet wasn't fully qualified. Just input the workbook name. If that's not it, post back.

Comment: Actually, try now :). I saw my mistake.